# Realtime db-view sync for a rails app. Recommendations

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, database, data-binding, ember.js

I'm building an app that will include a calendar for people to insert data both from their mobile and the web. The thing is, wherever they do it from, the view needs to update automatically when something changes on the database. 
I understand js frameworks like ember do this, but i have no experience with any of them. What approach would you recommend?

Comment: You need a framework that does 2-way data bindings. Ember doesn't do this off the bat since its only a front end framework and you would have to configure the backend to constantly update the front end. You should use a framework like Meteor (https://www.meteor.com/) which supports 2-way data bindings out of the box

Comment: Thanks @alalani, i'll take a look at that. On the other hand, sure you cannot accomplish this only with ember Observers and Binding?

Comment: I'm sure its possible, just very hard to do in practice. To give you a sense of how it might work: the backend needs to maintain active connections to all clients (probably via web sockets) and then push out all changes to the db to each client that the data is relevant to. This is a pretty complex set up in my opinion. Consider using something like Pusher instead to sync your data across clients